# JWT for Public .Net Core WebAPI

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am thinking of using a JWT to secure my .net Core WebAPI endpoints for a public API.   This API will only be consumed by a React front end that does not require a user to authenticate.  I am trying to ensure that only my React app can call my WebAPI endpoints.

My thought is to include the JWT when the React app is downloaded/initialized and use it when calling the API.

Thoughts on this?  Are there other more efficient ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
My thought is to include the JWT when the React app is downloaded/initialized and use it when calling the API.
```

I guess that way wouldn't work because I can copy the JWT token/API-Key or whatelse from network easily and use it for sending own requests. If your API is setup well (validation etc.), sending requests "manually" shouldn't be a problem. So why you only want your react app to request your app?

The only way (I guess) to give only your react app access to the API is to configure your API-server/proxy to accept only requests from the same domain.